# syntax error using perl dbi on copy into command

Tags: sql, perl, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a copy into table command that includes multiple dollar signs in the sql, all of which are escaped.  If I print out the actual command from the script and execute it manually it works perfectly.  But when the perl script does it I get a syntax error.  This is what I'm trying to execute, the printout from the command and then the sql error in turn, (I have assigned a $file in the script where it is inserting the data so that dollar sign doesn't get escaped below)

```
    my $sql = "COPY INTO metaproc.control_table FROM (
SELECT SPLIT_PART(METADATA\$FILENAME,'/',4) as SEAT_ID,
  \$1:auction_id_64 as AUCTION_ID_64,
 DATEADD(S,\$1:date_time,'1970-01-01') as DATE_TIME,
 \$1:user_tz_offset as USER_TZ_OFFSET,
 \$1:creative_width as CREATIVE_WIDTH,
 \$1:creative_height as CREATIVE_HEIGHT
 FROM \@DBNAME.lnd.S3_PROD_ADIP/$file)
pattern = '\.*\.parquet'  file_format = (TYPE = 'PARQUET' SNAPPY_COMPRESSION = TRUE)
ON_ERROR = 'SKIP_FILE_10%';";

 my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
 $sth->execute;
```

```
COPY INTO metaproc.control_table FROM (
SELECT SPLIT_PART(METADATA$FILENAME,'/',4) as SEAT_ID,
  $1:auction_id_64 as AUCTION_ID_64,
 DATEADD(S,$1:date_time,'1970-01-01') as DATE_TIME,
 $1:user_tz_offset as USER_TZ_OFFSET,
 $1:creative_width as CREATIVE_WIDTH,
 $1:creative_height as CREATIVE_HEIGHT
FROM @DBNAME.lnd.S3_PROD_ADIP/pr/appnexus/data_dt=20220217/19/STANDARD_20220218012146.gz.parquet)
pattern = '.*.parquet'  file_format = (TYPE = 'PARQUET' SNAPPY_COMPRESSION = TRUE)
ON_ERROR = 'SKIP_FILE_10%';
```

SQL compilation error: syntax error line 3 at position 4 unexpected '?'. syntax error line 4 at position 13 unexpected '?'. syntax error line 4 at position 13 unexpected '?'.

```
COPY INTO DWH_AIR.LND_APN.LND_STANDARD_IMP_EVENT FROM (
SELECT SPLIT_PART(METADATA$FILENAME,'/',4) as SEAT_ID,
  $1? as AUCTION_ID_64,
 DATEADD(S,$1?,'1970-01-01') as DATE_TIME,
 $1? as USER_TZ_OFFSET,
 $1? as CREATIVE_WIDTH,
 $1? as CREATIVE_HEIGHT
```

line 3 position 4 is the question mark after the '$1' on the 3rd line.  I don't get it, why is it removing the ':auction_id_64' part of the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is interpreting the : as a bind variable value, rather than a value in a variant.  Have you tried using the bracket notation, instead?

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-semistructured.html#bracket-notation

I believe it would look something like

```
COPY INTO metaproc.control_table FROM (
SELECT SPLIT_PART(METADATA$FILENAME,'/',4) as SEAT_ID,
  $1['auction_id_64'] as AUCTION_ID_64,
 DATEADD(S,$1['date_time'],'1970-01-01') as DATE_TIME,
 $1['user_tz_offset'] as USER_TZ_OFFSET,
 $1['creative_width'] as CREATIVE_WIDTH,
 $1['creative_height'] as CREATIVE_HEIGHT
FROM @DBNAME.lnd.S3_PROD_ADIP/pr/appnexus/data_dt=20220217/19/STANDARD_20220218012146.gz.parquet)
pattern = '.*.parquet'  file_format = (TYPE = 'PARQUET' SNAPPY_COMPRESSION = TRUE)
ON_ERROR = 'SKIP_FILE_10%';
```

I am uncertain whether this works or not, but if it doesn't, I will remove the answer.

Comment: Appreciate the reply Mike.  I am getting this error now, 'SQL compilation error: error line 3 at position 5 invalid identifier 'AUCTION_ID_64', after replacing those with open and closed brackets.  The brackets do appear in the snowflake returned failed sql query, unlike when I use the semi colon which for some reason turns into a question mark.  QQ, should I escape the brackets in the code, or leave them like you have it.

Comment: I looked at the docs link that you sent and I made a small change to your recommendation.  I put single quotes around the names inside the brackets, ['auction_id_64'], and that WORKED.  Wow man, thanks for the help.

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect your modification.  Thank you for getting back to me on this and working through it.  Glad it worked out for you.